# How can I solve this indentation problem in my Django project

Tags: python, django

[image]I'm a beginner in Django.
I was trying to add a method inside the OrderItem class. But the visual studio code is showing an indentation error.
I'm not sure what is wrong here.
Anyone can help me, please?

Here is the code:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# Create your models here.

class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Product(models.Model):    
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    price = models.FloatField()
    digital = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True, blank=True)
    #image needs to be added
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    @property
    def imageURL(self):
        try:
            url = self.image.url
        except:
            url = ""
    
        return URL



class Order(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    date_ordered = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True, blank=True)
    transaction_id = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id) 
   

class OrderItem(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1, null=True, blank=True)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    @property
    def get_total(self):
        return self.product.price * self.quantity
```

The indentation error is showing on the @property and get_total()

```
class OrderItem(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    @property
    def get_total(self):
        total = self.product.price * self.quantity
        return total
```

Pelase see the attached screenshot.

Comment: By properly indenting the `@property` decorator...

Comment: According to that screenshot and the plain-text code sample, the indentation appears to be correct.  Please update the question to include the full error traceback message, so we can tell what is really happening.

Comment: I have a feeling that VS code complains only because the blank line just before the property isn't indented.

Answer (score 2):

The `@property` decorator should be indented at the same level of the method and fields, so:

```
class OrderItem(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1, blank=True)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    @property
    def get_total(self):
        return self.product.price * self.quantity
```

Likely you want the `quantity` to be by default `1`. It is also not clear to me why that is a nullable field.

As a general rule-of-thumb please do *not* mix spaces and tabs. It might be better to *always* use spaces.

Comment: Thank you, it has worked. There were some extra blank spaces that were occurring the problem.